# Individual Package - Install

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I like to install a individual package, I think this works with sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-PACKAGE.

For my case I like to install the ar_kinect package, but when I try apt-cache search ros-fuerte there is not the ar_kinect package.

Can somebody tell me why?
Or how can I install this package?
(I use Ubuntu 10.04, ROS fuerte)

Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61693/individual-package---install/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think there is no .deb file available for this package. You should download the source and compile it yourself.

You should do something like:

```
rosws set ar_kinect https://github.com/mikeferguson/ar_kinect --git
rosws update 
roscd ar_kinect 
rosmake
```

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3